# Where is the Oracle WebLogic home in Mac OS?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, weblogic

I installed WebLogic server in Mac OS using the JAR file *oepe-12.1.3-kepler-installer-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.jar* downloaded from the Oracle website. Now, I'm trying to integrate it with Spring Tool Suite™ (STS) to run some web application.

As a part of the process, I need to include WebLogic Server 12c (12.1.3) in STS as running server and insert the address of the *WebLogic home* that I can't remember.

How to find out where is my ***WebLogic home*** in Mac OS ?

Note: I find a folder named oraInventory contains the following files: 
ContentsXML, logs and createCentralInventory.sh

The address of the folder is : /Users/myName/oraInventory
Do I need to provide this address is WebLogic home ?

[image]

### SOLUTION

I find the directory here: ***/Users/myName/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver***

Answer (score 1):

It will be the Middleware/wlserver directory. Typically something like this:

/Users/myName/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver/